# Correct syntax to write to Odoo many2many field with php API

Tags: php, odoo, xml-rpc, openerp-7

I am trying to update an existing sale.order by linking an existing invoice to it. I have tried several things to add the *invoice id* to the *invoice_ids* array of the sales order, but nothing is working.

Here is my code:

```
$link = $models->execute_kw($db, $uid, $password, 'sale.order', 'write',
array(array($order_id), 
array('invoice_ids'=>$invoice_id)));
```

This returns 1 but it does not change anything. I also tried this method but without success: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html#openerp.models.Model.write

I think there is something wrong with my syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this code:

```
#general syntax for many2many field
$many2many_field = array(
    new xmlrpcval(
        array(
            new xmlrpcval(6,"int"),
            new xmlrpcval(0,"int"),
            new xmlrpcval(array(new xmlrpcval($order_id,"int")),"array")
            ), "array")
    );

array('invoice_ids'=> new xmlrpcval($many2many_field, "array"))
```

Generally we need to give format like *[(6,0,[id1,id2,etc.])]*